# How enable/disable jasypt encryption at runtime?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jasypt

I have correctly integrated jasypt and Hibernate on a Sring Boot app.

Now I would like to disable/enable the encryption depending on the value of an environment variable.

Is it possible?